# How can I centralize URLs in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I made a mistake while writing my Django application in hard coding all the URLs in my templates.

For instance, my links look like:

```
<a href="/course/63/">Advanced Basketweaving</a>
```

Now, my client adamantly wants me to change all instances of links akin to this one to

```
<a href="/class/63/">Advanced Basketweaving</a>
```

where "class" replaces "course".

In the words of Emerson, a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, so I must pay for my mistake by undertaking a painstaking find and replace operation.

What was the right thing to do here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your urls.py had an entry like this:

```
url(r'^course/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', view_course, name='view_course')
```

You could have used the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in your template:

```
<a href="{% url view_course course.id %}">Advanced Basketweaving</a>
```

Then when your client asked you to change the urls, you would have to make only one change in your urls.py.

```
url(r'^class/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', view_course, name='view_course')
```

No change would be required in the templates.

Happy search and replacing -- now you know for next time ;)

Comment: The 3rd argument to `url` is `kwargs`, so I think you have to use `name='view_course'`.

Comment: Good spot, the URL patterns were broken. Now fixed.

Comment: If you happen to have MySQL installed, it comes with a great [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replace-utility.html) command, which comes in handy for these siutations.

Comment: @DrTyrsa This is hard to explain, but without `name='view_course'`, `'view_course'` by itself gets interpreted as the 3rd positional argument to `url` (`kwargs` -- which expects a dictionary), which won't work. Alasdair has since fixed it.

Comment: I made one tiny edit. I used raw strings for the URL pattern, as is customary. Otherwise you'd have to write `'\\d+'`. In other words, you don't have to escape the backslashes within raw strings.

Comment: @BrianNeal I think DrTyrsa might have meant that I could have changed it to `url(r'^class/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', view_course, {}, 'view_course')`. Personally, I prefer the `name='view_course'` as you suggested.

Comment: Because the URL pattern has a named capture argument `course_id`, do you have to write the URL tag like this: `{% url view_course course_id=course.id %}`? Or do both versions work?

Comment: @BrianNeal Why not to test it? When you do it, you will see that both versions work. The way you set `name` in `url()` has no matter at all. `{% url %}` (which is based on `reverse`) tries to load a corresponding view, not url record. If there is a view function which can accept these args and kwargs, match is found. And every function in python with limited amount of arguments can be called either with positional or named arguments.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing. I was commenting on this, which was in the original answer: `url(r'^course/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', view_course, 'view_course')`. The third argument to that is `'view_course'`. But if you look at the code, the third argument is `kwargs`. If you want to call the `url` function (not tag) with 3 arguments, you must do it like this: `url(r'^course/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', view_course, name='view_course')`.

Comment: @DrTyrsa Ok, I see you were now addressing my last question. I still don't understand your very first comment. Yes, the args version will work, but you need to supply `{}` for `kwargs` as a 3rd positional argument, and let name be the 4th positional argument.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the standard approach would be to use the [`url` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
{% url path.to.course_view 63 %}
```

...the main benefit being that you don't need to hardcode URLs. So it's a bit late now, but you might as well use the `url` tag this time around, just in case the client comes back tomorrow and wants them all to read `/classes/class/63` - at which point you'll only need to change the single URL pattern in your URLconf file.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed (after committing to your version control). One search and replace over your whole directory.

Here's a howto: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

You should probably also create a view which redirects the old-style urls to the new-style urls, in case of any bookmarks, or any links you missed.